# how to find an element with Jquery .find() that has been loaded with .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to load an html file in a div, this html have many elements inside. Soon after the file has been loaded, inside the div, I need to find a particular element, inside this html, to change its value.

I am using the following code:

```
var div = document.createElement('div'); 
$("#emptySpacee").append(div);       // insert the new div into the DOM
$(div).load('html/page.html', function(){      // load the page 
    $(div).find(".fieldName").val(1234);   //search using class name
});
```

The document is loaded but with jquery .find() I can not get the element.

I read many posts about this problem and it looks like everything depends on the fact that I am searching the element but the element has not been created yet in the DOM.

What should I do to start the search when all elements, loaded with the html file, can be searched with the Jquery.find() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting `$("#emptySpacee").find(div)` to chain `.load()` to , using `$(this).find(".fieldName").val(1234)` within `.load()` callback

```
var div = document.createElement('div'); 
var name = $.now();
div.className = name;
$("#emptySpacee").append(div);       // insert the new div into the DOM
$("#emptySpacee").find("[class=" + name + "]").load('html/page.html', function(){      // load the page 
    $(this).find(".fieldName").val(1234);   //search using class name
});
```

Comment: @OmarVassalli Try adding unique `className` to newly created `div` , selecting `div` by newly created `className` ? See updated post.

Comment: I tried with $(this).find    and it works but I can not use it because if a add new elements, with the same code, I will have many elements with the class (.filedName) that can be modified every time I add a new element. I tried the second solution by giving a different id to thediv but it does not work.

Comment: With `$(this).find()` only the elements inside the element to which `load` is applied are affected, so having the same code multiple times should not interfere with one and other. Although I'd still use $(div) instead of the classname construction to use with load. The classname construction seems superfluous. Or another shortcut version: `$('<div>').appendTo($("#emptySpacee")).load('html/page.html', function(){ $(this).find('.fieldName').val(1234);});`

Comment: I tried to loop your code in this way:
 for(i=0;i<5; i++){
    $('<div class="field">').appendTo($("#emptySpace")).load     ('html/page.html',   function(){ $(this).find('.fieldName').val(i); });
     }
and all the  5 elements created show the value of 5 !

Comment: Actually your code works. I made the mistake to use the var = i of the loop as value inside the function that is called when the control is loaded!!!

Comment: Does anyone know why using  $(div).find()  in this context does not work while the code posted bygest271314 and Me.Name does?

Comment: @OmarVassalli _"Does anyone know why using $(div).find() in this context does not work while the code posted bygest271314 and Me.Name does? "_ Not certain about `html` content of `'html/page.html'` ? jsfiddle of `js` at OP , only added selector at url provided to `.load()` http://jsfiddle.net/ckLv2eub/14/